# Get the information from a form into a database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get the information from this form into a database but get an error as below

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

```
<form action= "" method= "POST">
    <label for="title">Job title</label> <input type="text" name="title" /> <br>
    <label for="refcode">Reference Code</label> <input type="text" name="refcode" /> <br>
    <label for="salary">Salary</label> <input type="text" name="salary" /><br>
    <label for="location">Location</label> <input type="text" name="location" /><br>
    <label for="description"> Job description<textarea name="description" /> </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**My PHP file**

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO jobs (title, refcode, salary, location, description)
                                    VALUES(:title,:refcode,:salary,:location, :description) ');

$stmt-> execute($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is happen with the submit value of post variable, Didn't you try unset the element submit by post request.

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand your answer, can you try rephrasing?